# Restricting process rights

Tags: windows, process, filesystems, native, rights

I have a native Windows application which starts another process. Is it possible from the mother process to restrict the rights of the child process? I'm thinking along the lines of a sand box. The exact requirements aren't finished yet, but potentially I would like to restrict:

- Access to the file system
- Access to the registry
- Access to connected hardware (web cams, printers etc.)

I guess I could create a user with certain rights and start the process using that user, but that is not really a good solution in this case, as I might potentially end up with a large number of different processes each with their own set of required access rights. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Chrome's Windows sandbox architecture](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox#TOC-Sandbox-windows-architecture).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The Chromium Sandbox might not be directly suitable for this project, but using the underlying mechanisms described (restricted token, job object, desktop object and integrity levels) sounds very promising!